# Sulu: How to get the exact location of template errors in preview?

Tags: symfony, sulu

When I develop templates in Sulu 1.6 and an error occurs, where can I find the full error or exact error location? Is there some kind of special log or do I need to change the default location?

The corresponding `/admin/websocket/admin` response contains only this (basically the same information):

```
{
   "handler":"sulu_preview.preview",
   "message":{
     "code":9903,
     "message":"Unclosed \"block\".",
     "type":"Sulu\\Bundle\\PreviewBundle\\Preview\\Exception\\TwigException"
   },
   "options":[],
   "error":true
}
```

Currently I only see messages like this:
[image: Not very helpful template error]

It would be also helpful to know, where the catch block for this is, in case it is not jet implemented.

Thx a lot!

Comment: the catch block for this is located here: https://github.com/sulu/sulu/blob/master/src/Sulu/Bundle/PreviewBundle/Preview/Renderer/PreviewRenderer.php#L193

Comment: currently there is no special log implemented. i there any information in the response of the preview update?

Comment: Hi @Johannes Wachter, unfortunately the response provides also not the file and line number of the error. I updated the question with an admin socket response example,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turned out, that there is no logging enabled, and because the PreviewRendere throws a new Exception, the original information is pretty much lost. It can be added in this way: https://github.com/sulu/sulu/pull/4363

Best wishes
Andreas